# Will the process variable be saved if the activity in BPM Camunda crashes?

Tags: java, camunda

In the course of the activity, the variable is set `delegateExecution.setVariable("id", id)`.
Then the activity falls. Whether this variable will be saved?

Answer (score 2):

Camunda uses regular db transactions, so if by "fail" you mean that the executed code throws an exception, then: no, the transaction is rolled back and the variable is not stored.